# Magic link with custom text

Tags: feature-request, markdown

When I see a question not written in English, I will generally reply with a message in the relevant language asking for a translation.  A recent example in Italian:

> Benvenuto in Stack Overflow! Questo è un sito in inglese, e anche con una traduzione, questa domanda sarebbe fuori tema. Si prega di prendere il [tour] e visitare il nostro centro di aiuto ([help]) per imparare quali tipi di domande sarebbero in argomento, quindi modificare ([edit]) la domanda di conseguenza.

As you can see, the magic links are in English in brackets after the corresponding words in the foreign language.  Is there a way to condense this in order to have the magic link in the foreign language?  For example, `[modificare]([edit])`

Comment: Requested on MSE: [Extend comment magic links syntax to allow arbitrary link text](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/261753/)

Comment: I don't think there's much benefit in translating the magic links, since the pages they link to are still untranslated. Of course, the edit link just edits, but we do expect people to translate their question when they edit it.

Comment: You may want to search meta for existing discussions about flagging non-English *comments*. Generally there is no way to know if such comment is nice or unfriendly...

Answer (score 3):

On the face you've created what seems to be a good way to handle non-English questions, but there are two ***major*** pitfalls you're walking into:

1. **The OP now has an expectation that *someone* here speaks their language.**  That's presumptuous at best and disingenuous  at worst.  You're likely not going to get them to *accept* that English is the only allowed language here from that alone.  To complicate things, all of our help documentation is in English...
2. **This implies that these comments are the right thing to do *at all***.  They aren't; closing the question as "Unclear" is the sole course of action when presented with a question in a non-English language.